# How to identify multi-touch support in mobile browsers using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-touch

I am using `navigator.maxTouchPoints` to identify whether a device supports **multi-touch** or not. But this returns `undefined` in IPOD (9.3.3) and Android (lollypop)

```
function isMultiTouch(){
    return (window.navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1 || window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 1);
}
```

How to identify whether **multi-touch** is supported or not in mobile devices?

**Edit:**

maxTouchPoints worked only in windows mobile. In android and iOS mobiles, it is not working.

[Multi-touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-touch)

[What is Multi-touch](http://www.touchscreen-me.com/about-touch-screens-multi-touch.php)

[Touch gestures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543(v=vs.85).aspx)

Above links explain about multi-touch and gestures.

Comment: detecting a touch device is not what I want. I want to detect whether the device supports gestures like pinching, multi-finger swipe, etc.,

Comment: @esqew, if you don't know what gestures are then why are you marking it as duplicate. You don't even know the difference between touch and multi-touch. Once you learn about gesture and multi-touch you will understand my question